# When trying to implement an io.Reader that uses channels I get a fatal error

Tags: go

I apologise for the very simple question, just having some trouble wrapping my head around how we implement `io.Reader`.

My final use case is that I am consuming an endless stream that can send data at any time. To simulate this I have created an `emitter` that implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`.

I listen to the reader using a `bufio.Scanner` concurrently, while sending values to any listener from main.

Playground:
https://goplay.space/#eJfe0HyfYrL

```golang
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    data := newEmitter()

    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(data)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    data.WriteString("foo")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    data.WriteString("bar")

    wg.Wait()
}
```

My `emitter`

```golang
type emitter struct {
    ch chan []byte
}

func (em *emitter) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n := copy(b, <-em.ch)
    return n, nil
}

func (em *emitter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    em.ch <- b
    return len(b), nil
}

func (em *emitter) WriteString(s string) (int, error) {
    return em.Write([]byte(s))
}

func newEmitter() *emitter {
    return &emitter{
        ch: make(chan []byte),
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Comment: Oh great! io.Pipe is exactly what I am trying to make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goroutine blocks in `emitter.Read` on receive from `<-em.ch`. The main goroutine blocks on `wg.Wait`. Deadlock!

Fix by adding a `Close()` method to emitter to close `em.ch`. Return `io.EOF` in `emitter.Read` when the channel is closed. `Close` the emitter when done sending data.

There are other issues with the `emitter`. Instead of fixing `emitter`, use [io.Pipe](https://godoc.org/io#Pipe) to connect the writer to the reader:

```
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)

pr, pw := io.Pipe()

go func() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(pr)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    wg.Done()
}()

io.WriteString(pw, "foo\n")
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
io.WriteString(pw, "bar\n")
pw.Close()

wg.Wait()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rzQTz-6NNr7).